# Non linear trend analysis in java

Tags: java, math, non-linear-regression, trend

I'm currently working on an Java Project where I constantly (e.g. very 10 seconds) receive an y-value with an continues incrementing x-value representing the x and y axis of a graph.

e.g.:

```
    // First value is x, second is y - addData(<x-value>,<y-value>)
    sr.addData(1, 2.43);
    // 10 seconds later
    sr.addData(2, 2.41);
    // 10 seconds later
    sr.addData(3, 2.48);
    // 10 seconds later
    sr.addData(4, 2.51);
    // 10 seconds later
    sr.addData(5, 2.49);
    // etc etc
```

I would like to calculate the latest trend (rising or falling and how strong the trend is - something like `getSlope()` when using `SimpleRegression` from `math3`). But while these point are mostly non linear and can rise or fall I would like to use some non linear regression instead of linear regression (which I'm currently using by only adding the latest 3-4 values which is in my opinion not very accurate).

I stumbled upon `LoessInterpolator`. But I'm not quite sure how to use it and how I could calculate the slope. Are there any examples on that? Is it recommended to use `LoessInterpolator` for my needs or are they any other ways how to calculate a trend/slope quite accurate?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can still use linear regression.  You'll want to fit coefficients for a nonlinear function.  A polynomial should do.  Are you looking for regression trend lines or spline fitting?  You should look into Kalman filter.  You don't want to redo the entire history every time a new data point comes in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter